# Querying from a DataTable to retrieve information based on DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, datatable

My question might be a bit long coz i've tried to explain the context behind it.

I have a `DataTable` (retrieved from a database) which contains the following data:

```
----------------------------------
-  State -         Date          -
==================================
-   on   -  02/01/2016 15:38:13  -
----------------------------------
-   off  -  22/01/2016 16:45:33  -
----------------------------------
-   on   -  27/01/2016 10:30:16  -
----------------------------------
-   off  -  01/02/2016 10:03:43  -
----------------------------------
```

I need to check the state depending on the date. Any date in between will have the previous date's state. Example: 29/01/2016 will have the state as 'On'.

I tried to query from the `DataTable` as such :

```
DateTime test = DateTime.Parse("27 / 01 / 2016"); //temporary part
var queryResults = table.AsEnumerable()
                           .Where(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Field<string>("Date")).Date == test);
```

Right now that query above returns the row where the condition is fulfilled. If i change the where statement in the query to `Where(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Field<string>("Date")).Date <= test);` it returns the first three rows.

**My question is ..**
If i change the test value to 28/01/2016 with the less than or equal query it will still return the first three rows. How can i get the last one only? The last state.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Just add `.LastOrDefault().` to you query

Comment: @StephenMuecke ... that worked! :D i had no clue it existed. If you could enter it as an answer, i would like to mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.LastOrDefault()` to get the last item in the collection

```
var queryResults = table.Where(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Field<string>("Date")).Date <= test).LastOrDefault();
```

Sid enote: You should check for `null` before accessing the `State` property

Answer (score 0):

You should order by them in descending date then get the first one

```
 queryResults = table.Where(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Field<string>("Date")).Date <= test).OrderByDescending(y=>y.Field<string>("Date")).FirstOrDefault();
```